# Identity server 4 Sliding expiration for reference token

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'd like to prolong lifetime of reference token whenever user makes request to an API. Is it possible? Is there any build in mechanism in IS4 that intended for that purpose?
The main purpose is to expire reference token if user is not active (didn't make requests to API).

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing, but I know there is a mechanism to get a "refreshed" (new?) token if your current one expires.  I also remember there is a mechanism for reducing the lifetime of your token.  Obviously this impacts performance somewhat for the overhead to refresh the token.

The mechanics are in the ID4 documentation.  Been awhile since I've looked at it.  Hope this gets you going!

Comment: What you are saying and sliding expiration are not the same. Unfortunately, refresh token doesn't feet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, that is not possible. As @john mentioned, it is possible to get a new token or keep using the existing one by using refresh token to IDS4. That means you have to pass the refresh token to the API.

What I'll do is using a JWT with a short lifetime (like 30 mins) and refreshing it before expiry from client side (from SPA).